# Text not formatted after adding CSS files

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js

I'm new web development and I'm working on a login registration application. The bootstrap.css file is under the public folder. I've tried to clear my browsing history and cache but the text doesn't appear in a formatted manner once I run it on localhost. Would appreciate some advice and suggestions.

Following is present in layout.handlebars under the layouts folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Login Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header clearfix">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
    <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row marketing">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
  </footer>

</div> <!-- /container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Following is the style.css script

```
    /* Space out content a bit */
    body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */
.header,
.marketing,
.footer {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

/* Custom page header */
.header {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */
.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/* Custom page footer */
.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

/* Customize container */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 730px;
  }
}
.container-narrow > hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

/* Main marketing message and sign up button */
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  padding: 14px 24px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

/* Supporting marketing content */
.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.marketing p + h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}

/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but there is no opening `<body>` tag. What does your console say, are the stylesheets loading properly?

Comment: @hcs sorry, edited the html portion. I don't get any messages on the console. Ran $node app on gitbash after which tried to the load the page in a browser. The text gets displayed but not in a formatted manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using bootstrap css style you need the public CDN: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

When you use it like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" >` - it's mean the css of bootstrap is on your computer like the css file you created (`style.css`)